# Reading Letters in Lines

Tags: java

I have this code right now that reads the lines of the txt document. I am trying to add some code that will make it so that the program only prints the lines of text that start with the letter C and A. Could anyone help me?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class FileTester
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner sf = new Scanner(new File("amazinggrace.txt"));
        int maxIndx = -1;
        String text[] = new String[1000];

        while(sf.hasNext( ))
        {
            maxIndx++;
            text[maxIndx] = sf.nextLine( ) ;
        }
        sf.close( );
        {
            System.out.println( text[j] );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at `startsWith(...)` in the docs.

Comment: C and A or it's a combination too? like "CA" or "AC"

Comment: And just as side note: reading strings in an array from file, and printing (parts) of the ARRAY content aren't necessarily related. Meaning: you can start with a simple array that has 3 hardcoded strings in it ... that makes writing the "printing" code much easier. And then, when your "printing" code works as expected, then you let it print that array you read from file.

Comment: Also note: read about proper Java code indentation. You should put your { braces at the end of a line, and be consistent about using always the same indentation. Such things matter. They make your code easy to read, or hard to read. Finally: it is not good practice to throw code at us that doesnt even compile. It seems your one print statement is supposed to sit in a for loop ... but it doesn't. Seriously: dont take your non-working code and throw it at other people. You want others to spend their time to help you, so you please provide proper input to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using list since you cannot predict how much of lines you will be adding to the result.
Check the following code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class FileTester {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        Scanner sf = new Scanner(new File("amazinggrace.txt"));
        List<String> text = new ArrayList<>();

        while (sf.hasNextLine()) {
            String current = sf.nextLine();
            if(current.startsWith("C") || current.startsWith("A"))
                text.add(current);
        }
        sf.close();
        System.out.println(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this was super helpful!

Comment: @2Cold4u Consider accepting the answer if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `String.startsWith()` method inside of the while loop you have there to check if the line begins with a specific character/characters, and then use `System.out.println()` to print the line as you do later in the code.

You can find the documentation for `String.startsWith()` here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

When reading and or writing to files, it's good practice to close the resources when finished processing. You can read more info on this here :https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

See my example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<String> text = new ArrayList<>();

    File file = new File("amazinggrace.txt");

    try (FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
         BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader)){

        String line = bufferedReader.readLine();

        while (line != null)
        {
            if (line.startsWith("A") || line.startsWith("C")) {
                text.add(line);
            }

            line = bufferedReader.readLine();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to open file, file not found.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to read file." + file.getName());

    }
```